# Plotly Graph Objects set viewable size

Tags: plotly, plotly.graph-objects

I am trying to draw some squares in a ploty application. I realized that ploty sometimes decides the size of the viewable area based on the objects inside it (which makes sense) but other times its just fixed regardless of whats drawn. I want to override it so I can set some shapes without them getting deformed.

I found [fig.update_layout](https://plotly.com/python/setting-graph-size/) but it seems to update the actual "canvas" size but not how the dimensions of what is shown inside are calculated nor the boundaries

In my example I have two rects whos distance between its corners is the same so they should look like squares; also I'd like to set the top corner to be further away (meaning that the squares inside would look smaller

This is my simplified example:

#### Code

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

fig.update_layout(
    autosize=False,
    width=500,
    height=500,
    paper_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
    # I'd like to set the corner to be 10,10
)

# Set axes properties
fig.update_xaxes(showgrid = False, zeroline = False, visible = False)
fig.update_yaxes(showgrid = False, zeroline = False, visible = False)

fig.add_shape(type="rect",
    x0=0, y0=0, x1=4, y1=4, # this should look like a big square going a little before the middle of the screen
    line=dict(color="Red"),
)
fig.add_shape(type="rect",
    x0=1, y0=1, x1=2, y1=2, # this should look like a small square inside the first one
    line=dict(color="Red"),
)

fig.show()
```

#### Obtained Result

[image]

#### Expected Result

[image]

Comment: My understanding of your question may be lacking, but if the y-axis and x-axis have the same range, it will be a square. `fig.update_xaxes(range=[0,4], showgrid = False, zeroline = False, visible = False);fig.update_yaxes(range=[0,4], showgrid = False, zeroline = False, visible = False)`

Comment: Well, it seems that it works. Its weird cause I had in my go.Layout( xaxis=dict(range=[0, 5], autorange=False, zeroline=False), (for both axis which look like should do something similar but somehow it did not work but this does. This library is not nearly as intuitive as I was told to. Thanks @r-beginners If you post this as an answer Ill mark it as the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having had the opportunity to respond, I will give some case examples of the limitations of the axis.
The first is to set a scale anchor.[Reference](https://plotly.com/python/axes/#fixed-ratio-axes)

```
fig.update_layout(yaxis=dict(scaleanchor='x'))
```

[image]

The above example is equivalent to the following code. `fig.update_layout(yaxis=dict(scaleanchor='x', scaleratio=1.0))` The aspect ratio can be changed by changing the scale ratio.

```
fig.update_layout(yaxis=dict(scaleanchor='x', scaleratio=2.0))
```

[image]

I commented that in the example of the figure in the question, I thought it would be easier to draw the figure with the additional limitation of the axes.

```
fig.update_xaxes(range=[0,4], showgrid=False, zeroline=False, visible=False)
fig.update_yaxes(range=[0,4], showgrid=False, zeroline=False, visible=False)
```

[image]